# C# Pass several classes as one parameter

Tags: c#, class, oop, methods, parameters

I have 2 classes that hold some info about the user. One holds the data, the other one holds the controls info. Now i need to pass both of them as a parameters to a method. However they are connected to one another and i dont think that passing the 2 classes separately as parameters is okay. I wonder if i should put them in a `Tuple` or something that keeps them together so i can pass them as just 1 parameter to any method. Here's how they look :

**The data class** :

```
public class UsersProperties
{
    public enum CUser
    {
        Player,
        Bot1,
        Bot2,
        Bot3,
        Bot4,
        Bot5
    }

    public int RightCard { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? Chips { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public bool Turn { get; set; }
    public bool FoldTurn { get; set; }
    public int PreviousCall { get; set; }
    public int LeftCard { get; set; }
    public double Power { get; set; }
    public int EnumCasted { get; set; }
}
```

**The controls class** :

```
public class UserControls
{
    public Point CardsLocation { get; set; }
    public AnchorStyles CardsAnchor { get; set; }

    public Panel Panel { get; } = new Panel();
    public Point PanelLocation { get; set; }
    public Size PanelSize { get; } = new Size((Settings.Width + 10) * 2, Settings.Height + 20);
    public int IndentationPanelXy { get; } = 10;

    public Label UsernameLabel { get; set; } = new Label();
    public Point UsernameLabelLocation { get; set; }
    public Size UsernameLabelSize { get; } = new Size(Settings.Width * 2, 20);

    public TextBox ChipsTextBox { get; set; } = new TextBox();
    public Label StatusLabel { get; set; } = new Label();

    public UserControls(AnchorStyles style, Point cardsLocation, bool down)
    {
        CardsAnchor = style;
        CardsLocation = cardsLocation;
        UsernameLabelLocation = down ? new Point(CardsLocation.X, CardsLocation.Y - 20) : new Point(CardsLocation.X, CardsLocation.Y + Settings.Height);
        PanelLocation = new Point(CardsLocation.X - IndentationPanelXy, CardsLocation.Y - IndentationPanelXy);
    }
}
```

Now here's how i initialize them :

```
private static Player Player = new Player(Properties.Settings.Default.StartingChips);

private UserControls PlayerControls = new UserControls(AnchorStyles.Bottom, new Point(560, 470),false);
```

And here's the method where i need to pass both of them :

```
        private void SetPlayers(UsersProperties user, UserControls userControls, int turn, ref bool check, Image refreshbackImage)
    {
        if (user.Chips <= 0) return;
        _foldedPlayers--;
        if (turn < user.RightCard || turn > user.LeftCard) return;
        if (Holder[user.RightCard].Tag != null)
        {
            Holder[user.LeftCard].Tag = _reserve[user.LeftCard];
        }
        Holder[user.RightCard].Tag = _reserve[user.RightCard];
        if (!check)
        {
            _horizontal = userControls.CardsLocation.X;
            _vertical = userControls.CardsLocation.Y;
        }
        check = true;
        Holder[turn].Anchor = userControls.CardsAnchor;
        Holder[turn].Image = refreshbackImage;
        if (turn < Bot1.RightCard)
        {
            Holder[turn].Image = Deck[_i];
        }
        Holder[turn].Location = new Point(_horizontal, _vertical);
        _horizontal += Holder[turn].Width;
        Holder[turn].Visible = true;
        Controls.Add(userControls.Panel);
        userControls.Panel.Location = userControls.PanelLocation;
        userControls.Panel.BackColor = Color.DarkBlue;
        userControls.Panel.Size = userControls.PanelSize;
        userControls.Panel.Visible = false;
        if (_i != user.LeftCard) return;
        check = false;
    }
```

I want to know if there's any better way to pass 2 classes as parameters i think they should stick together anyway.

Comment: If you want to put them in a container class, then do so. But there's nothing that says you shouldn't just give two objects as parameters. Putting them in a tuple would just make it more complicated and wouldn't give anything to you

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper class (ie:UserContainer) which has two properties namely, usercontrol and userproperty. 
Then initialize it and pass this class as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Generics, as in here:

```
namespace PropertiesControls
{
    public class PropsControls
    {
        public static void PropesAndControls<TP, TC>(TP property, TC control) where TP : UserProperties where TC: UserControls
        {
            //your code here
        }
    }
}
```

A generic defines a behaviour that can be applied to a class. It is used in collections, where the same approach to handling an object can be applied regardless of the type of object. I.e, a list of strings or a list of integers can be handled using the same logic without having to differentiate between both specific types.